# NOAUTH Authentication required. Laravel + Redis

Tags: redis, laravel-5.3, predis

I am getting error **NOAUTH Authentication required**.
My laravel version is 5.3 and I am using predis 1.1.1 to connect redis.

in etc/redis/redis.conf I have:

```
bind 127.0.0.1
requirepass somepassword
```

in .env file I have

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=somepassword
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

in config/database.php I have:

```
'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
```

I am connecting redis via:

```
self::$_db = \Redis::connection('default');
```

and using it like:

```
self::$_db->pipeline(function ($pipe) use ($profile, $time,$type, $id) {
            $pipe->zadd(self::getProfileKey($profile, $type), $time, $id);
            $pipe->zadd(self::getProfileKey($profile), $time, $type . ':' . $id);
            $pipe->zadd(self::getModelKey($type,$id) . '::favoritedBy', $time, $profile->profile_id);
        });
```

So, when I comment out `requirepass` and send password as null it works but it does not work and throw error `NOAUTH Authentication required.` when the password is in place. I need to have password in place as per my project requirement. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So after some research, I got a solution for this issue:

We need to add:

```
'options' => [
                'parameters' => ['password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null)],
            ],
```

In `config` array. See complete example below: database.php

```
'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 3,
        ],
        'options' => [
            'parameters' => ['password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null)],
        ],
    ],
```

In .env file:

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=mmdgreat
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Comment: For what it's worth, on Laravel 6.0.3 with PhpRedis (the PECL extension) and redis-cli 3.0.6, this isn't necessary; it would be ideal to mention which Redis server version you're using. Maybe this additional configuration is a result of using Predis and an older version of Redis.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error in **Symfony**, specifically `symfony/cache`.
Problem was that `REDIS_DSN` environment variable did not contain password information, but redis docker container required the password.
So changing this:

```
REDIS_DSN=redis://<redis-host-name>:6379
```

to this

```
REDIS_DSN=redis://<redis-password>@<redis-host-name>:6379
```

Symfony cache config:

```
framework:
    cache:
        default_redis_provider: '%env(REDIS_DSN)%'
        pools:
            my_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.adapter.redis
```

In PHP you can also check the credentials this way:

```
    $redis = new \Redis([
        'host' => 'redis-host-name',
        'port' => 6379,
        'auth' => 'redis-password',
    ]);
```

Note: I did not find symfony specific question in stack overflow, so decided to add answer here.

Answer (score -3):

I solve it downgrading the predis! :D

```
composer require predis/predis:0.8.4
```

I'm using the Laravel 5.3 too! :)