# Rails + Redis : Redis::CommandError (NOAUTH Authentication required.):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I searched and found some post related about this problem, espacially this one [NOAUTH Authentication required. Laravel + Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482945/noauth-authentication-required-laravel-redis), but it doesn't solved my problem.

Redis + Rails ( with `dotenv-rails` ) + Ubuntu

Errors:

`Redis::CommandError (NOAUTH Authentication required.)`

In **development** the app is OK, but in **production** ( deploy with `cap` ) got this error.

In **production** with **Redis** without password the app is OK, but add password got this error.

*etc/redis/redis.conf* :

```
bind 127.0.0.1
requirepass somepassword
```

*.env*

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=somepassword
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

*config/initializers/redis.rb*

```
Redis.current = Redis.new(:host => ( ENV["REDIS_HOST"] || '127.0.0.1'),
                          :port => ( ENV["REDIS_PORT"] || '6379').to_i,
                          :password => (ENV["REDIS_PASSWORD"] || ''))
```

And I test the `ENV["REDIS_HOST"]` in rails console, output is `127.0.0.1`.

I want to know how to enable **Redis**'s password in this situation?

Thanks

---

**EDIT**

I run `auth the_password` in `redis-cli`, the ouput is `OK` and same as the value of `ENV["REDIS_PASSWORD"]` from the production rails console.

And now the rails log display `Redis::CommandError (ERR invalid password)` .

I'm very confused about it.

**Edit again**

I changed `redis.rb` to below and it **worked**:

```
Redis.current = Redis.new(:host => ( ENV["REDIS_HOST"] ),
                          :port => ( ENV["REDIS_PORT"] ).to_i,
                          :password => ( ENV["REDIS_PASSWORD"] ))
```

Comment: Are you sure your environment variables are loading properly? You can check these variable in rails console in productiom environment and check for these values if they are loaded properly or not

Comment: There are same. I run `auth the_password` in `redis-cli`, the ouput is `OK` and same as the value of `ENV["REDIS_PASSWORD"]` from the production rails console. And now the rails log display `Redis::CommandError (ERR invalid password)` .

Comment: Check output of `ENV['REDIS_PASSWORD']` in RAILS CONSOLE in production environment. I'm not talking about redis console.

Comment: Thank you @AakashGupta . Now it's OK after I did some changes like  in the **Edit again** .